# TYPO3 add filemetadata to backend TCA IRRE element

Tags: typo3, fal

I would like to add additional metadata (e.g. copyright) to an image in tt_content (the standard IRRE field in TYPO3 8.7).

I intalled the "filemetadata" extension to get these additional fields. If I open a sys_file_reference, I have access to the fields. Now I want to show the copyright field to the tt_content IRRE "image" field, which is currently showing the standard fields"title,description,link".

I tried to override the TCA (myExtension/Configuration/TCA/Override/tt_content.php):

```
'image' => [
    'label' => 'LLL:EXT:lang/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.images',
    'config' => \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::getFileFieldTCAConfig('image', [
        'appearance' => [
            'createNewRelationLinkTitle' => 'LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:images.addFileReference'
        ],
        // custom configuration for displaying fields in the overlay/reference table
        // to use the imageoverlayPalette instead of the basicoverlayPalette
        'overrideChildTca' => [
            'types' => [
                '0' => [
                    'showitem' => 'copyright,
                            --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                            --palette--;;filePalette'
                ],
                \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_TEXT => [
                    'showitem' => '
                            --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                            --palette--;;filePalette'
                ],
                \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_IMAGE => [
                    'showitem' => '
                            --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                            copyright,--palette--;;filePalette'
                ],
                \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_AUDIO => [
                    'showitem' => '
                            --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.audioOverlayPalette;audioOverlayPalette,
                            --palette--;;filePalette'
                ],
                \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_VIDEO => [
                    'showitem' => '
                            --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.videoOverlayPalette;videoOverlayPalette,
                            --palette--;;filePalette'
                ],
                \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_APPLICATION => [
                    'showitem' => '
                            --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                            --palette--;;filePalette'
                ]
            ],
        ],
    ], $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['GFX']['imagefile_ext'])
],
```

and like this in the localconf of myExtension:

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['sys_file_reference']['types'] =[
        '0' => array('showitem' => 'uid_local,uid_foreign,tablenames,fieldname,title,description,copyright'),
];
```

but the copyright field will not appear.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a dirty solution.
The main Problem is, that sys_file_metadata is not related to sys_file_reference!

I fixed my problem:

1. New UserFunc in TCA sys_file_reference na dset a new palette

EXT:myext/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/sys_file_reference.php:

```
$metaDataSysFileReferenceColumns = [
'metadata' => array (
    'exclude' => 1,
    'label' => 'Metadata',
    'config' => array (
        'type' => 'user',
        'userFunc' => \VENDOR\MyExt\UserFunction\ProviderField::class . '->getMetaData',
    )
```

)];
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTCAcolumns('sys_file_reference', $metaDataSysFileReferenceColumns);
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addFieldsToPalette('sys_file_reference', 'metaPalette', 'metadata');

2. Userfunction ProviderField->getMetaData()
   public function getMetaData(array $parameters, $parentObject)
   {

   ```
       $uid = $parameters['row']['uid_local'][0]['uid'];

       $sys_language_uid = 0;
       if (!empty($parameters['row']['sys_language_uid'])) {
           $sys_language_uid = $parameters['row']['sys_language_uid'][0];
       }

       $queryBuilder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\ConnectionPool::class)
           ->getQueryBuilderForTable('sys_file_metadata');
       $recordInDatabase = $queryBuilder
           ->select('*')
           ->from('sys_file_metadata')
           ->where(
               $queryBuilder->expr()->eq(
                   'file',
                   $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter($uid, \PDO::PARAM_INT)
               ),
               $queryBuilder->expr()->eq(
                   'sys_language_uid',
                   $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter($sys_language_uid, \PDO::PARAM_INT)
               )
           )
           ->setMaxResults(1)
           ->execute()
           ->fetch();

   $html = array();
   $html[] = '
       <div class="row">
           <div class="form-group t3js-formengine-validation-marker t3js-formengine-palette-field col-sm-6">
               <label class="t3js-formengine-label">
                   Creator
               </label>
               <div class="formengine-field-item t3js-formengine-field-item">
                   <div class="form-control-wrap" style="max-width: 480px">
                       <div class="form-wizards-wrap">
                           <div class="form-wizards-element">
                               <div class="form-control-clearable">
                                   <input type="text" id="formengine-input-'.uniqid().'"
                                           class="form-control t3js-clearable hasDefaultValue"
                                           data-formengine-validation-rules="[{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;trim&quot;}]"
                                           data-formengine-input-params="{&quot;field&quot;:&quot;data[sys_file_metadata]['.$recordInDatabase['uid'].'][creator]&quot;,&quot;evalList&quot;:&quot;trim&quot;,&quot;is_in&quot;:&quot;&quot;}"
                                           data-formengine-input-name="data[sys_file_metadata]['.$recordInDatabase['uid'].'][creator]"
                                           data-formengine-input-initialized="true">
                                   <button type="button" class="close" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
                                       <span class="t3js-icon icon icon-size-small icon-state-default icon-actions-close" data-identifier="actions-close">
                                           <span class="icon-markup">
                                               <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                                   <path d="M11.9 5.5L9.4 8l2.5 2.5c.2.2.2.5 0 .7l-.7.7c-.2.2-.5.2-.7 0L8 9.4l-2.5 2.5c-.2.2-.5.2-.7 0l-.7-.7c-.2-.2-.2-.5 0-.7L6.6 8 4.1 5.5c-.2-.2-.2-.5 0-.7l.7-.7c.2-.2.5-.2.7 0L8 6.6l2.5-2.5c.2-.2.5-.2.7 0l.7.7c.2.2.2.5 0 .7z" class="icon-color"></path>
                                               </svg>
                                           </span>
                                       </span>
                                   </button>
                               </div>
                               <input type="hidden" name="data[sys_file_metadata]['.$recordInDatabase['uid'].'][creator]" value="'.$recordInDatabase['creator'].'">
                           </div>
                           <div class="form-wizards-items-aside">
                               <div class="btn-group"></div>
                           </div>
                           <div class="form-wizards-items-bottom"></div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
           <div class="form-group t3js-formengine-validation-marker t3js-formengine-palette-field col-sm-6">
               <label class="t3js-formengine-label">
                   Source
               </label>
               <div class="formengine-field-item t3js-formengine-field-item">
                   <div class="form-control-wrap" style="max-width: 480px">
                       <div class="form-wizards-wrap">
                           <div class="form-wizards-element">
                               <div class="form-control-clearable">
                                   <input type="text" id="formengine-input-'.uniqid().'"
                                           class="form-control t3js-clearable hasDefaultValue"
                                           data-formengine-validation-rules="[{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;trim&quot;}]"
                                           data-formengine-input-params="{&quot;field&quot;:&quot;data[sys_file_metadata]['.$recordInDatabase['uid'].'][source]&quot;,&quot;evalList&quot;:&quot;trim&quot;,&quot;is_in&quot;:&quot;&quot;}"
                                           data-formengine-input-name="data[sys_file_metadata]['.$recordInDatabase['uid'].'][source]"
                                           data-formengine-input-initialized="true">
                                   <button type="button" class="close" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
                                       <span class="t3js-icon icon icon-size-small icon-state-default icon-actions-close" data-identifier="actions-close">
                                           <span class="icon-markup">
                                               <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                                   <path d="M11.9 5.5L9.4 8l2.5 2.5c.2.2.2.5 0 .7l-.7.7c-.2.2-.5.2-.7 0L8 9.4l-2.5 2.5c-.2.2-.5.2-.7 0l-.7-.7c-.2-.2-.2-.5 0-.7L6.6 8 4.1 5.5c-.2-.2-.2-.5 0-.7l.7-.7c.2-.2.5-.2.7 0L8 6.6l2.5-2.5c.2-.2.5-.2.7 0l.7.7c.2.2.2.5 0 .7z" class="icon-color"></path>
                                               </svg>
                                           </span>
                                       </span>
                                   </button>
                               </div>
                               <input type="hidden" name="data[sys_file_metadata]['.$recordInDatabase['uid'].'][source]" value="'.$recordInDatabase['source'].'">
                           </div>
                           <div class="form-wizards-items-aside">
                               <div class="btn-group"></div>
                           </div>
                           <div class="form-wizards-items-bottom"></div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
           <div class="form-group t3js-formengine-validation-marker t3js-formengine-palette-field col-sm-6">
               <label class="t3js-formengine-label">
                   Copyright
               </label>
               <div class="formengine-field-item t3js-formengine-field-item">
                   <div class="form-control-wrap" style="max-width: 480px">
                       <div class="form-wizards-wrap">
                           <div class="form-wizards-element">
                               <div class="form-control-clearable">
                                   <input type="text" id="formengine-input-'.uniqid().'"
                                           class="form-control t3js-clearable hasDefaultValue"
                                           data-formengine-validation-rules="[{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;trim&quot;}]"
                                           data-formengine-input-params="{&quot;field&quot;:&quot;data[sys_file_metadata]['.$recordInDatabase['uid'].'][copyright]&quot;,&quot;evalList&quot;:&quot;trim&quot;,&quot;is_in&quot;:&quot;&quot;}"
                                           data-formengine-input-name="data[sys_file_metadata]['.$recordInDatabase['uid'].'][copyright]"
                                           data-formengine-input-initialized="true">
                                   <button type="button" class="close" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
                                       <span class="t3js-icon icon icon-size-small icon-state-default icon-actions-close" data-identifier="actions-close">
                                           <span class="icon-markup">
                                               <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                                   <path d="M11.9 5.5L9.4 8l2.5 2.5c.2.2.2.5 0 .7l-.7.7c-.2.2-.5.2-.7 0L8 9.4l-2.5 2.5c-.2.2-.5.2-.7 0l-.7-.7c-.2-.2-.2-.5 0-.7L6.6 8 4.1 5.5c-.2-.2-.2-.5 0-.7l.7-.7c.2-.2.5-.2.7 0L8 6.6l2.5-2.5c.2-.2.5-.2.7 0l.7.7c.2.2.2.5 0 .7z" class="icon-color"></path>
                                               </svg>
                                           </span>
                                       </span>
                                   </button>
                               </div>
                               <input type="hidden" name="data[sys_file_metadata]['.$recordInDatabase['uid'].'][copyright]" value="'.$recordInDatabase['copyright'].'">
                           </div>
                           <div class="form-wizards-items-aside">
                               <div class="btn-group"></div>
                           </div>
                           <div class="form-wizards-items-bottom"></div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
           <div class="form-group t3js-formengine-validation-marker t3js-formengine-palette-field col-sm-6">
               <label class="t3js-formengine-label">
                   Publisher
               </label>
               <div class="formengine-field-item t3js-formengine-field-item">
                   <div class="form-control-wrap" style="max-width: 480px">
                       <div class="form-wizards-wrap">
                           <div class="form-wizards-element">
                               <div class="form-control-clearable">
                                   <input type="text" id="formengine-input-'.uniqid().'"
                                           class="form-control t3js-clearable hasDefaultValue"
                                           data-formengine-validation-rules="[{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;trim&quot;}]"
                                           data-formengine-input-params="{&quot;field&quot;:&quot;data[sys_file_metadata]['.$recordInDatabase['uid'].'][publisher]&quot;,&quot;evalList&quot;:&quot;trim&quot;,&quot;is_in&quot;:&quot;&quot;}"
                                           data-formengine-input-name="data[sys_file_metadata]['.$recordInDatabase['uid'].'][publisher]"
                                           data-formengine-input-initialized="true">
                                   <button type="button" class="close" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
                                       <span class="t3js-icon icon icon-size-small icon-state-default icon-actions-close" data-identifier="actions-close">
                                           <span class="icon-markup">
                                               <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                                   <path d="M11.9 5.5L9.4 8l2.5 2.5c.2.2.2.5 0 .7l-.7.7c-.2.2-.5.2-.7 0L8 9.4l-2.5 2.5c-.2.2-.5.2-.7 0l-.7-.7c-.2-.2-.2-.5 0-.7L6.6 8 4.1 5.5c-.2-.2-.2-.5 0-.7l.7-.7c.2-.2.5-.2.7 0L8 6.6l2.5-2.5c.2-.2.5-.2.7 0l.7.7c.2.2.2.5 0 .7z" class="icon-color"></path>
                                               </svg>
                                           </span>
                                       </span>
                                   </button>
                               </div>
                               <input type="hidden" name="data[sys_file_metadata]['.$recordInDatabase['uid'].'][publisher]" value="'.$recordInDatabase['publisher'].'">
                           </div>
                           <div class="form-wizards-items-aside">
                               <div class="btn-group"></div>
                           </div>
                           <div class="form-wizards-items-bottom"></div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>';
   return implode(LF, $html);
   ```

   }
3. Last step override the assets (FileReference) in tt_content:
   EXT:myext/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php:
   'assets' => [
       'label' => 'LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/Database.xlf:tt_content.asset_references',
       'config' => \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::getFileFieldTCAConfig('assets', [
           'appearance' => [
               'createNewRelationLinkTitle' => 'LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/Database.xlf:tt_content.asset_references.addFileReference'
           ],
           // custom configuration for displaying fields in the overlay/reference table
           'overrideChildTca' => [
               'types' => [
                   '0' => [
                       'showitem' => '
                       --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;metaPalette,
                       --palette--;;imageoverlayPalette,
                       --palette--;;filePalette'
                   ],
                   \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_TEXT => [
                       'showitem' => '
                       --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;metaPalette,
                       --palette--;;imageoverlayPalette,
                       --palette--;;filePalette'
                   ],
                   \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_IMAGE => [
                       'showitem' => '
                       --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;metaPalette,
                       --palette--;;imageoverlayPalette,
                       --palette--;;filePalette'
                   ],
                   \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_AUDIO => [
                       'showitem' => '
                       --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;metaPalette,
                       --palette--;;imageoverlayPalette,
                       --palette--;;filePalette'
                   ],
                   \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_VIDEO => [
                       'showitem' => '
                       --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;metaPalette,
                       --palette--;;imageoverlayPalette,
                       --palette--;;filePalette'
                   ],
                   \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_APPLICATION => [
                       'showitem' => '
                       --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;newsPalette,
                       --palette--;;imageoverlayPalette,
                       --palette--;;filePalette'
                   ]
               ],
           ],
       ], $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['mediafile_ext'])
   ],

Voila, each Media Element in tt_content will show the additional metadata infos on collapsing IRRE. I know, it's really dirty...

Answer (score 0):

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['sys_file_reference']['ctrl']['types']
```

should be

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['sys_file_reference']['types']
```

Unsure if there are further issues.

Comment: You are right, I had a typo... I applied the change to in my initial question. BUT this doesn't solve my problem. I think this problem is related to TCA palettes. Further suggestions?